# htlatex requires graphic file extensions "jpg" while other latex variants don't. What to do?

Tags: graphics, external-files, htlatex

I am trying to make a book that is published in both print and ebook format, and I would like one source for the book that works in both media.   When I compile the following with `xelatex` it works.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\chapter{Authors}
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.28\textwidth]{graphics/jimphoto}
\end{wrapfigure}
\end{document}
```

When compiled with `htlatex` I get an error:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `graphics/jimphoto' not found.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.8 ...cs[width=0.28\textwidth]{graphics/jimphoto}
```

However, if I change "jimphoto" to "jimphoto.jpg" I do not get this error.  It seems, when you specify the file extension, it sees the file.

Does this mean that I need to go through and change the entire source file, to every mention of a graphic and put the file extensions on all the graphic files.  Elsewhere I have been told to leave it off because something else in latex works better that way.  Or is there something else I am missing?

Answer (score 9):

You need to declare extensions which should LaTeX try when including graphics. You can use `\DeclareGraphicsExtensions` in the custom config file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.jpg,.png,.gif,.svg}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

save this as `myconfig.cfg` and compile with

```
make4ht -c myconfig.cfg filename.tex
```

LaTeX now should try each to include image basename with each of `jpg, png, gif` and `svg` extensions until existing file is found and this file is then used.

Comment: This has a "begin" without a corresponding "end".   Is that going to work?

Comment: @AgilePro I reworded my last sentence, I hope it does make more sense now.