# LuaLaTex + MakeIndex + BibTex to html or docx file

Tags: bibtex, luatex, makeindex

Is there any way to convert my (LuaLaTex + MakeIndex + BibTex) main.tex from MikTex file to html or docx?

I've tried this https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/73092/189401 but it's not what I want.

These are the packages I'm importing in the preamble:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\usepackage{setspace}

\setlength{\topmargin}{-2.5cm}

\usepackage[top=2.50cm, bottom=2.50cm, left=3.00cm, right=2.00cm]{geometry}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhf{} 

\rfoot{\thepage} 

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} 

\usepackage[LGR, T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel} 

\usepackage[unicode, linktoc=all]{hyperref} 

\usepackage{mwe}

\usepackage{graphicx} 

\graphicspath{{images/}} 

\usepackage{easyfig}

\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{cleveref}

\crefname{figure}{figure}{figures}

\Crefname{figure}{Figure}{Figures} 

\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=black, urlcolor=black, citecolor=black}

\usepackage[bibencoding=auto,backend=bibtex,autolang=other,sorting=none]{biblatex}

\renewcommand\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}

\usepackage{csquotes} 

\addbibresource{bib.bib} 

\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{tabulary}

\usepackage[12pt]{moresize} 

\usepackage{abstract} 

\renewcommand{\abstractnamefont}{\normalfont\large}

\renewcommand{\abstracttextfont}{\normalfont\normalsize}


\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

\usepackage{xcolor} 

\usepackage{import} 

\begin{document}
```

Comment: there are many convertors, latexml, tex4ht, lwarp, ... but whether they work with luatex depends in some cases how much lua you are using, and you give no clues.  also saying "not what you want" does not tell anyone what you do want.

Comment: you can also simply import the generated pdf into word and see what it does (I am told)

Comment: `make4ht -ul filename.tex` for html or `make4ht -ulf odt  filename.tex` for ODT. You will need to configure it for makeindex and bibtex. it is impossible to say anything more without some additional inforamtion about problems you encountered and especially a code sample

Comment: I've tried what you said, but it says that it can't read my figures.

Comment: I need a full example including the figure code and the error messages from the command line output. common issue may be that you don't use filename extensions in the `\includegraphics` command. see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/213473/2891 for a fix.

Comment: I'm using something like this and my text is in greek

\renewcommand{\figurename}{\textbf{Εικόνα}}
\renewcommand\thefigure{\textbf{4.1.1}}
\Figure[width=\textwidth,placement=H,caption={\textbf{Εύρεση πύλης δικτύου.}}]{cied}

And in the command says that cied file not found

Comment: yes, it seems to be the issue I was talking about. did the fix from my previous command work? It would be best, if you could edit your answer also with a real code after `\begin{document}`

Comment: Now it says that I haven't got titlepage, but I'm using \begin{titlepage}....
Nevermind, I will leave it as it is. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I've added some sample code to your example and tried it with `make4ht`. It compiles mostly OK, I've just had to remove few unnecessary packages (don't use `fontenc` and `inputenc` together with `fontspec`, also, don't use BibTeX commands with BibLaTeX)

Here is the modified example:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

% \setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\usepackage{setspace}

\setlength{\topmargin}{-2.5cm}

\usepackage[top=2.50cm, bottom=2.50cm, left=3.00cm, right=2.00cm]{geometry}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhf{} 

\rfoot{\thepage} 

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} 

% \usepackage[LGR, T1]{fontenc}

% \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[greek,english]{babel} 

\usepackage[unicode, linktoc=all]{hyperref} 

\usepackage{mwe}

\usepackage{graphicx} 

\graphicspath{{images/}} 

\usepackage{easyfig}

\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{cleveref}

\crefname{figure}{figure}{figures}

\Crefname{figure}{Figure}{Figures} 

\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=black, urlcolor=black, citecolor=black}

\usepackage[bibencoding=auto,backend=biber,autolang=other,sorting=none]{biblatex}

% \renewcommand\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}

\usepackage{csquotes} 

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib} 

\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{tabulary}

\usepackage[12pt]{moresize} 

\usepackage{abstract} 

\renewcommand{\abstractnamefont}{\normalfont\large}

\renewcommand{\abstracttextfont}{\normalfont\normalsize}


\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

\usepackage{xcolor} 

\usepackage{import} 
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}
Hello world. Some indexing.
\index{hello}
\index{hello!Peter}
\index{Jenny|textbf}

Some citation \cite{gillies}

\printbibliography
\printindex
\end{document}
```

The index and bibliography creation can be automated using `make4ht` build file. It needs the development version of `make4ht` for the correct index. Save the following code as `mybuild.lua`:

```
if mode=="draft" then
Make:htlatex {}
else
Make:htlatex {}
Make:xindy {}
Make:biber {}
Make:htlatex {}
end
```

The document can be compiled using command

```
make4ht -ule build.lua filename.tex
```

The subsequent compilations, when the bibliography and index hadn't changed, can be speed up using

```
make4ht -ule build.lua -m draft filename.tex
```

It will execute LaTeX only once, it will not execute Xindy nor Biber.

Here is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try `pandoc` - https://pandoc.org/

The command line should be something like this:

```
pandoc -s --toc my.tex -o my.html
```

Comment: It says that I haven't got titlepage, but I'm using \begin{titlepage}